# I created an application layout in Scene Builder and connected it to Intellij Idea. And when I press the "run" button in Intellij Idea nothing happens

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rvpS.png)

I created an application layout in Scene Builder and connected everything to Intellij Idea. But when I press the start button, nothing happens, it doesn't even give errors.
I don't understand what the problem is.This is the first time I've encountered this

Comment: anything pop up if you click the "..."?

Comment: hi there, did you import the scene builder code to IDE as an fxml? And could you also provide your codes for further discussion

Comment: As mentioned, you need to provide your code (as a [mcve]).  Probably you didn't call `show()` on your stage, so there is nothing to see, but you may have another issue.

Comment: Have you set the `FXML's` controller?